# Selenium error - org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException session created exception

Tags: selenium, junit

I am using Eclipse 4.6 with Selenium Chrome webdriver and this is my first JUnit program. Simple Junit code to open a web page.

I get the following error:

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception

from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"5969CD1AFF4A18EA209C33F54E3D5CD1","isDefault":true,"type":"default"},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}

(Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)

(Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Command duration or timeout: 3.43 seconds

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'

System info: host: 'Y6H224', ip: '10.888.888.71', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'

Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

```
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)

            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)

            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)

            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:54)

            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using chromedriver=2.20.353145 with chrome browser 75. chromedriver 2.20 does not support latest chrome versions. Download driver version which supports Chrome 75.

You can download it from here,
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.140/

Comment: Chirag, I will try and let you know. thank you

Comment: I don't know how to mark this question as completed or working